# Update at most one row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to perform an `update` but I want to only execute it if *exactly* one row fulfills the `where` condition.

Alternatively perform the update if several rows fulfill the `where` condition, but only update *one* row. (`limit` clause?)

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea. May I ask why you need this?

Comment: @shawnt00 I don't think I can explain you the details of the problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rownum` to limit the statement. For example:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET some_column = 'test'
WHERE ...
AND rownum = 1;
```

This will act more in a limiting sense as you describe. It will update just one row regardless of how many rows the rest of the `WHERE` clause captures.